# Devise - login from two model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have two user models, first is from remote database as legacy and for internal company purposes. (Employee logins). Second is our project for public registration and sign in but I want one login form. I have searching long time, but some solutions are confusing for me.

First legacy looks like (only for reading and authentication):

```
class CrmUser < ActiveRecord::Base

  require Rails.root.join('lib', 'devise', 'encryptors', 'sha1')
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :rememberable, and :omniauthable
  establish_connection "crm_data"
  set_table_name :users

  devise :database_authenticatable, :encryptable, :authentication_keys => [:login]
  alias_attribute :encrypted_password, :crypted_password
  alias_attribute :password_salt, :salt

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :login, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :role_id, :first_name, :last_name
```

And second, for public and registration:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :rememberable, and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :authentication_keys => [:login]
  alias_attribute :login, :email

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :login, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :role_id, :first_name, :last_name
```

Now I don't know how to do that User controller try to authentication from first model, and when user doesn't exists, go to second model and try it again.

Using:

- Rails 3.1
- Devise 1.4.3

EDIT:

In wiki of Devise is something about multiple model, but I'm little bit confused, there are not example more complex.

Thank you.

Regards, Rado

Comment: From this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254431/devise-authentication-from-two-models i have an idea how it may work. But i dont know any solution. Nobody solve this problem before ?

Answer (score 2):

You should monkeypatch `find_for_authentication` method from `devise/models/authenticatable.rb`

```
module Devise
  module Models
    module Authenticatable
      def find_for_authentication(conditions)
          #put your authentication logic here
        end
    end
  end
end
```

About authentication logic:
Using two models for authentication in your case it's realy bad idea. How do u want build relations with two users models? It's a lot of unnecessary code.

Correct way of resolving your problem is make some synchronization between yours tables.

- Try to authenticate user with base User model.
- If user credentials was wrong - try to authenticate him with CrmUser model.
- If authentication with CrmUser was OK **add him to users table** if he doesn't exists there already.
- Return User's model object.