# Devise in mogoid for multi-users with different data

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, mongoid3

I am using rails 3.2.7, mongoid 3, and i am trying to use devise for users accounts.

Before i'll start: i was searching a lot for my problem, and i read many tutorials, byt none fit to my need.

I have similar problem like [devise and multiple “user” models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9472852/devise-and-multiple-user-models)

but i am using mongodb so i think the problem is not exacly the same.

I have 3 types of users":

1. Manger which can have many places and can manage them(edit info).
2. User which can search for places(even no user can) and create their places lists. Also user can comment and note the places.
3. Administrator who can edit/delete anythig, so admin is a god.

So, all of them have different data(except of login info) and i don't know what solution is the best.

STI would be good if they would have the same data, and different actions, but data are different too(but i am using mongoid, so maybe it would be fine?)

Single user model with roles is another solution but i don't know how to store different data, maybe with polymorphic? I don't fully understand how it should be implemented with devise and maybe cancan.

Maybe there is third?

I know what is STI, polymorphic associations, also how to implement roles with CanCan, but the problem is that i dont't know how to connect them with devise?

If there would be few sign in forms or one, it doesn't matter. I don't have to use devise either.

I found few tutorials/examples how to use devise, monogid, roles for multi-users applications, but they are when users store the same data, so they don't fit for me.

Can you give me advice, or a maybe a link which could help me?

Thanks for help :)

Comment: You can build different controllers for different users and store data without dependencies to the roles. Simply create controllers for different use cases.

Comment: Well, for now i made STI with one controller, but without Devise. I made it from scratch. I am going to make like you suggested, i will use Devise with 3 different controllers.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend building different controllers for different use cases. Don't build dependencies of different views inside the data. This way you are free to use the data for other use cases or other user groups without changing it directly.

Simply create controllers for the different use cases. This way you can change them any time without changing your data model.