# devise and multiple users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, multiple-users

I am trying to have Devise create a single User model and have different roles be a separate model. My User model (from rails g devise User) has a email, first name, last name, and role field.

The roles are admin, spectator, competitor. So, I created admin, spectator, and competitor models who all inherit from the User model.

I followed the top answer from [devise and multiple "user" models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9472852/devise-and-multiple-user-models) and I can create a user. However, my competitor model migration also has other information such as contest name and location that are not required for the other models. When I do Competitor.create() and put in the necessary information for creating a devise User, the User gets stored in the database even though I have null constraints on the competitor model for contest name and location.

When I do Spectator.all, the recently created competitor data shows up which I thought it shouldn't....

My question is how should I be setting this up so that a competitor user doesn't get created unless his contest name and location is provided.

Another question is why when I do Spectator.all is the competitor's information displaying?

Comment: You'll need to post some code.  The null constraint should work, did you remigrate?  Does the describe table 'competitors' look ok?

Comment: Check out [this](https://github.com/EppO/rolify/wiki/Tutorial) tutorial on using devise, cancan, and roify. I've used this setup before and it works really well.

Answer (score 1):

There is a much better way to use devise for multiple users.

Use [Rolify Gem](https://github.com/EppO/rolify)

It makes development much easier faster and more secure. You can have the configuration as per your requirement in the question "**Single User model and each roles have a separate model**"

[Tutorial for using Rolify gem + Devise by Rolify Gem developers](https://github.com/EppO/rolify/wiki/Tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

If you want an authorization system, so go for [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) created by Ryan Bates. With CanCan you can have many Roles. I am using it with devise with no problems. See [Role Based Authorization](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Role-Based-Authorization) and [Separate Role Model](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Separate-Role-Model). And check this [ScreenCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan) about CanCan