# How to use with_options for conditional validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How can I use `with_options` for conditional validation ?

My code is

```
with_options if: (AppUser::User.creator=="is_admin") do |admin|
  admin.validates :first_name, :presence => true
  admin.validates :last_name, :presence => true
end
```

I have already set `creator` method in application controller.

```
before_action :set_global_user

def set_global_user
  if current_admin
    AppUser::User.creator= "is_admin"
  elsif current_user
    AppUser::User.creator= "is_user"
  else
    AppUser::User.creator=nil
  end
end
```

but I am getting

> undefined method `validate' for false:FalseClass

what is wrong with this code.

Answer (score -1):

because

```
(AppUser::User.creator == "is_admin")`
```

does not return an object but it is a boolean.

Try this (inside your model):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  with_options if: (AppUser::User.creator == "is_admin") do
    validates :first_name, presence: true
    validates :last_name, presence: true
  end
end
```

P.S: I recommend the use of the devise gem to manage user types like this:
[devise and multiple “user” models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9472852/devise-and-multiple-user-models).