# Ruby on Rails - Devise Authentication error with STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I implemented multiple users with devise, following steps of this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9472852/devise-and-multiple-user-models#9473095)

I generate models per type of user and extends from Users Model. Then, I add a column named `type` with string datatype to the user table in the database using a migration.

But, when I login with whatever user I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Devise::SessionsController#create
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'type' in 'field list': UPDATE `users` SET `last_sign_in_at` = '2015-05-16 15:51:00', `current_sign_in_at` = '2015-05-26 22:49:23', `sign_in_count` = 10, `updated_at` = '2015-05-26 22:49:23' WHERE `users`.`id` = 1
```

Thanks for your advice! Sorry for my english.

Comment: It seems you there is no 'type' field in database. Do you create this field in database (migration)?

Answer (score 1):

Run:

```
rails g migration add_type_to_users type:string
```

then:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```