# Removing a Devise user model possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Is there a way to remove a previously generated devise model? I had generated 2 models with devise: `user` and `student`. Now I'm having trouble with the 2 different login pages and their routes, so I decided to switch to a single table inheritance solution (following a suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9472852/devise-and-multiple-user-models)).

So I want to keep the devise model `user` and generate 2 models with `rails g model ...` that inherit from the user model: `teacher` and `student`.

But since I already have a devise model named student I was wondering if I could somehow delete the existing model and corresponding db table, or if it was enough to simply delete these 2 lines from the model:

```
# app/assets/models/student.rb
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think devise offers a generator that would bring your model back to a previous version (similar to `rails destroy migration ...`). Apart from removing the `devise` method call from your model, you would need to get rid of the table itself (in a migration) and all the generated templates and controllers referring to the `Student` model, just to keep things clean.